# FLTK application shows window behind it as foreground color

Tags: fltk, centos8

No matter the widget and using a new, from-source build of FLTK 1.3.9 on Centos8, I get a large amount of transparency on the foreground color.  It renders fine when placed over a black window or desktop.  The same code base works well on my OpenSuse machine.

[Here's the codebase root](https://github.com/dholstei/BashGuiHelper)
[image: Weird Transparency]

Note also, it doesn't make a difference the settings for `OPTION_USE_SYSTEM_LIBJPEG` or `OPTION_USE_SYSTEM_LIBPNG`, nor the `color()` methods for the base window or widget window.